# Disabling delta compression in git for a single remote

Tags: git

I have a bare git repo used that is used as remote.  That repo serves fetches
via git-daemon.

I do not want delta compression to be done in the server the repo is, as the
resources it uses sometimes cause performance problems.

From the doc I am not clear what of these two options would be the correct one:

1. Add a `* -delta` in info/attributes file, in the bare repo in the server.
2. Commit a file .gitattributes to the repo with `* -delta`.

If the second option is used, it seems like only would apply to some branches,
and then it would apply also for every remote (I only want to disable it in one), so
I suspect option 1 to be the right one, but I was not able to find confirmation in docs.

Is that correct?  May I assume git-daemon does not need to be restarted?
(problems only happens with many, many concurrent fetches, so verifying that
editing info/attributes is enough is not easy).

Comment: Overly short answer: yes, both are correct (use option 1, no restart).